# Is there an easy way in VB.Net to have dynamic number of panels can be created like text in listview?

Tags: vb.net

I want to have dynamic number of panels displayed on the screen. Its like creating listview of panels. I would like something that would allow me to use .add and .remove operators to add and remove panels from listview or some other control. Is there anything out there right now in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx), which you can use to add any controls to it (in your case, more panels).